# Equivalence Principle: Uniform to Non-uniform gravitational fields

Tags: general-relativity, gravity, spacetime, geodesics, equivalence-principle

1. [image: geodesic eq will hold in non uniform gravity]

[2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IlpR6.jpg)Einstein in his 1916 GR paper describes the equivalence principle and makes a case for general relativity i.e a person in a non-inertial frame is equivalent to a person in a uniform gravitational field but inside a frame which is inertial (e.g., a frame fixed to the surface of the earth). Guided by this principle and the fact that metric tensor $g_{\mu\nu}$ encodes info about acceleration and therefore should encode info about gravity, he derives the equation of motion for the particle i.e the geodesic equation ( in arbitrary coordinates). Uptil now, it is all about uniform gravitational fields but then he suddenly declares that this equation will continue describing motion of a particle even when the gravitational field is non uniform which in his language means metric cannot be made equal to flat metric in a finite region. He gives some justification for doing this but it is not clear to me at all. How can equivalence principle which is a local statement about equivalence with uniform gtavitational fields lead to general geodesic equation which is true for arbitrary gravitational fields?

Comment: It would help if you would link to the text of the paper that you are using and refer to specific sections of the paper. I think that I know which paper you mean, but he did write more than one paper that year. And it is a big paper so I am pretty unclear about what parts you are asking

Comment: I have added the images from his paper. The text below Eq(46). Also, the text in [2] hyperlink. In both these places what he is doing( in my understanding) is,  using arguments about equivalence of  uniform gravity and inertial forces and then suddenly generalising them to non-uniform gravitational fields ( which can create tides ). In his language he is generalising it to a situation where the laws of SR do not hold in a finite region. I hope it is clear now.